# Switching urls in HtmlUnit

Tags: htmlunit

Is there any way to change the url with session in HtmlUnit?

My case is like here below,

1. Login to http://test.raja.com with credentials.
2. Get page http://home.raja.com, it should get my home page as logged in.

In browser this is perfectly fine. But in HtmlUnit, I can get only test.raja.com not homepage. I tried WebWindow, WebConnection, addCookie etc but nothing works.

Found this in https://community.jboss.org/wiki/UsingTheHtmlUnitAPIWithJSFUnit

> Getting a new URL in the same browser session
>
> If you want to simulate the user typing a URL into the browser session
>   or need to do a GET request for any other reason, you need to use the
>   WebClient and JSFUnit's WebConversationFactory as in this example:
>
> JSFSession jsfSession = new JSFSession("/index.jsf"); WebClient
>   webClient = jsfSession.getWebClient();
>   webClient.getPage(WebConversationFactory.getWARURL() +
>   "/myotherpage.jsf");
>
> JSFSession, JSFServerSession, and JSFClientSession will stay in sync
>   with the WebClient and you can continue to use those objects normally.
>   Also, the HttpSession will be the same because the WebClient will
>   continue to set the JSESSIONID cookie.

Is this possible in HtmlUnit itself?

my sample code

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://home.raja.com");     
final List<FrameWindow> window = page.getFrames();
final HtmlPage pageTwo = (HtmlPage) window.get(0).getEnclosedPage();//this is test.raja.com served via iframe
HtmlForm form = pageTwo.getFormByName("login");
HtmlInput userName = (HtmlTextInput)form.getInputByName("testone");
HtmlInput password = (HtmlPasswordInput)form.getInputByName("testtwo");
userName.setValueAttribute("guest");
password.setValueAttribute("guest");
HtmlInput submit = (HtmlSubmitInput)form.getInputByName("submit");
HtmlPage pagethree = (HtmlPage)submit.click();
page = webClient.getPage("https://home.raja.com");      //here it again goes for login page
```

Answer (score 3):

Issue solved. Used the following code,

```
webClient.setRedirectEnabled(true);
webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);                                             
webClient.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);             
webClient.setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);  
webClient.setUseInsecureSSL(true);
webClient.setCssEnabled(true);
webClient.setAppletEnabled(true);
webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);
```